# SQLAlchemy join 3 tables ans select bigger count()

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have 3 entities: Seller, Customer, ProductBought.

ProductBought is assigned to a Customer, and Customer is assigned to Seller.

Each of these entities has an id field.

What is the SQLAlchemy query to select the id of the Seller who has more BoughtProduct?

I have come up with this query, but doesn't work:

```
best_seller = dbs.query(Seller).\
    join(Customer).\
    join(ProductBought).\
    filter(and_ (Seller.id_ == Customer.id_, Customer.id_ == BoughtProduct.id_)).\
    order_by(count()).\
    first()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like this: first you make a sub-query that aggregates per-customer sales data, then perform aggregate query on sellers joined to this sub-query.

```
customers = (session
    .query(Customer.seller_id, func.count().label('bought_count'))
    .join(ProductBought)
    .group_by(Customer)
    .subquery())
result = (session
    .query(Seller, func.sum(customers.c.bought_count).label('total_sales'))
    .join(customers, Seller.id==customers.c.seller_id)
    .group_by(Seller)
    .order_by(desc('total_sales'))
    .first())
```

Complete code with model definitions and sample data initialization:

```
from sqlalchemy import (create_engine, event,
    Column, Integer, String,
    ForeignKey,
    desc, func)
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr

from random import choice


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sellers.db', echo=True)
event.listen(engine, 'connect',
    lambda conn, rec: conn.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;'))
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


class Base(object):

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        clsname = self.__class__.__name__
        return '<%s(%d)>' % (clsname, self.id)


Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)


class Seller(Base):
    pass


class Customer(Base):
    seller_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Seller.id), nullable=False)
    seller = relationship(Seller, backref='customers')


class Product(Base):
    pass


class ProductBought(Base):
    product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Product.id), nullable=False)
    product = relationship(Product, backref='sales')
    customer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Customer.id), nullable=False)
    customer = relationship(Customer, backref='purchases')


def prepare_data():
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    session = Session()

    sellers = [Seller() for _ in xrange(5)]
    customers = [Customer(seller=choice(sellers)) for _ in xrange(20)]
    products = [Product() for _ in xrange(10)]
    sales = [ProductBought(product=choice(products), customer=choice(customers))
        for _ in xrange(100)]

    session.add_all(sellers + customers + products + sales)

    session.commit()
    session.close()


def top_seller():
    session = Session()

    customers = (session
        .query(Customer.seller_id, func.count().label('bought_count'))
        .join(ProductBought)
        .group_by(Customer)
        .subquery())
    result = (session
        .query(Seller, func.sum(customers.c.bought_count).label('total_sales'))
        .join(customers, Seller.id==customers.c.seller_id)
        .group_by(Seller)
        .order_by(desc('total_sales'))
        .first())

    session.close()
    return result


def main():
    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    prepare_data()
    print top_seller()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Excellent explanation Rkhayrov! Now I understand everything much better!